# ASP.NET MVC get data from another table and link together

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a system which lists all of data employees and their email and ext etc. I've got this working fine with a search.

Model:

```
namespace ServiceDirectory.Models
{
    [Table("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public String Forename { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Surname")]
        public String Surname { get; set; }
        public String Ext { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ServiceDirectory.Models.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Employee", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search By:</b> @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Surname", true) <text>Surname</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Forename") <text>ForeName</text><br />
    @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Ext</th>
            <th scope="col">Job Title & Location</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var Employee in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>@Employee.Forename @Employee.Surname</td>
            <td>@Employee.Ext</td>
            <td>Job Title here</td>
            <td>@Employee.Email</td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Controller:

```
namespace ServiceDirectory.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db;

        public EmployeeController()
        {
            db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
        {
            if (searchBy == "Forename")
            {
                return View(db.Employee.Where(x => x.Forename.StartsWith(search)).Where(e => e.Active).ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                return View(db.Employee.Where(x => x.Surname.StartsWith(search)).Where(e => e.Active).ToList());
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

In my view you will see "Job Title here", what I want to do is get the job title to display for each employee, my issue is that its in another table called `EmployeeDetails`.

How can I link into `EmployeeDetails` to get the job title and link it into my employee view?

Any help would be appreciated, this is my 1st project :)

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-joining-operator-join

Comment: Can you show EmloyeeDetails class too, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a class (view model) something like this below. You would list down the properties you want to display. I name it EmpVM

```
 public class EmpVM
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public String Forename { get; set; }

    public String Surname { get; set; }
    public String Ext { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public String JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller you use Linq join to join Employee table and Employee detail and push the result as EmpVM class

```
  public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {

        List<EmpVM> Employee = new List<EmpVM>();
      


            var Emp = (from E1 in db.Employee
                       join E2 in db.EmployeeDetail
                       on E1.EmployeeID equals E2.EmployeeId
                       select new EmpVM
                       {
                           EmployeeID = E1.EmployeeID,
                           Forename = E1.Forename,
                           Surname = E1.Surname,
                           Ext = E1.Ext,
                           Email = E1.Email,
                           Active = E1.Active, 
                           JobTitle = E2.JobTitle
                       });

        if (searchBy == "Forename")
        {
            Emp.Where(a => a.Forename.StartsWith(search) && a.Active == true);
        }
        else
        {
            Emp.Where(a => a.Surname.StartsWith(search) && a.Active == true);
        }


        Employee = Emp.ToList();

        return View(Employee);

    }
```

The view will be very simple. You just need to display the collection. It goes like (remember to replace your own namepsace)

```
@model IEnumerable<Incendo.Web.Models.EmpVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>



@*Your search method here*@

<table class="table table-condensed ">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>@item.Forename @item.Surname</td>
        <td>@item.Ext</td>
        <td>@item.Email</td>
        <td>@item.JobTitle</td>
    </tr>

  

}
</table>
```

I have not tested it life but I think it should work. Let me know your result.

Comment: Thats great, Linq is not something I've come accross so I'll have to take a look into that. I'm getting a list now with job titles in thank you. My only issue is that the search doesnt seem to be work, I just get a long list including all inactive, any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Did u insert the html.BeginForm section to the view? Try to Insert a break point in the controller index and check the searchby and search value. One more thing, I strongly recommend u to use pagination for this.

Comment: @Matt , Hi I realise I've missed out some code on the filter part. I've created the test program and it is working. Meanwhile, please check the edited answer. Surely works!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it working by adding return View(Emp.Where(a => a.Forename.StartsWith(search) && a.Active == true)); and that seems to have done the trick, and stops the long list appearing at the start. I just need some help with Linq adding 3rd table. but I'll create another thread for that. Thats for your help, always good to learn something as well as getting it to work! Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093157/linq-mvc-getting-job-name-from-job-id/67094047#67094047

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by having a view model. I assume your EmployeeDetail class like below

```
 public class EmployeeDetail
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
  }
```

Create a ViewModel for the purpose and name it as EmployeeVM

```
 public class EmployeeVM
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeDetail> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

In your Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {

        List<EmpVM> Employee = new List<EmpVM>();
      


            var Emp = (from E1 in db.Employee
                       join E2 in db.EmployeeDetail
                       on E1.EmployeeID equals E2.EmployeeId
                       select new EmpVM
                       {
                           EmployeeID = E1.EmployeeID,
                           Forename = E1.Forename,
                           Surname = E1.Surname,
                           Ext = E1.Ext,
                           Email = E1.Email,
                           Active = E1.Active, 
                           JobTitle = E2.JobTitle
                       });

        if (searchBy == "Forename")
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                Emp = Emp.Where(a => a.Forename.StartsWith(search) && a.Active == true);
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                Emp = Emp.Where(a => a.Surname.StartsWith(search) && a.Active == true);
            }
        }


        Employee = Emp.ToList();

        return View(Employee);

    }
```

In your View

```
@model IEnumerable<Incendo.Web.Models.EmpVM>

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<b>Search By:</b> @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Surname", true) 
<text>Surname</text>
@Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Forename") <text>ForeName</text>
<br />
@Html.TextBox("search")
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<table class="table table-condensed ">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>@item.Forename @item.Surname</td>
        <td>@item.Ext</td>
        <td>@item.Email</td>
        <td>@item.JobTitle</td>
    </tr>



}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I'm having issues with my view it does not recognise the model Inendo as I already have a model in my view I cant use 2?

Comment: U need to change that according to ur project namespace

Comment: Amazing thanks and even learned something on the way! 1 question tho, how do I get the JOB to go into the 1st for each loop? is that possible?

Comment: The first loop is from the Employee that generate item (refer to each employee that in the model). The 2nd loop is loop according to the first loop item that produces item1 that refers to the employees detail that refer to the item. That where the  Model.EmployeeDetails.Where(a => a.EmployeeId == item.EmployeeID) comes into play.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I guess what I'm looking for is it possible to have like this        <td>@item.Forename @item.Surname</td>
        <td>@item.Ext</td>
        <td>@item1.JobDescription</td>
        <td>@item.Email</td>

Item and Item1 in same foreach loop

Comment: Of course that is possible but you may assume one employee only has on Job Description. If Employee has more than one Job Description, the same employee will show out twice. Maybe you could show how's your view wanna look like.

Comment: Thanks again for reply @Yat Fei Leong I posted my original view, basicly A table which list my employees but I want the job description to show in the same table.
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Ext</th>
            <th scope="col">Job Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
        </tr>

Comment: Haha.. That's even simpler, I post the answer afterwards.

Comment: That will be a great help thanks I've been pulling my hair out! @Yat Fei Leong