# Linq + MVC getting Job Name from Job ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL Database with 3 tables

- Employee
- EmployeeDetails
- Job

I used Linq to link Employee and Employee Details together so now I have a table which list all of employees and a JobID which is referenced in EmployeeDetails Table. So when I run my project it looks like below;

**Name Extension Job Title Email**

|Matt| Ext 0000 | 56 | email@email.co.uk

Now what I want to do is link into the 3rd table which is called Jobs, to change ID 56 and do actually get the job name.

I've created my Model and my View model;

Below is my controller

```
namespace ServiceDirectory.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext db;

        public EmployeeController()
        {
            db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
        {

            List<EmpVM> Employee = new List<EmpVM>();


            var Emp = (from E1 in db.Employee
                       join E2 in db.EmployeeDetails
                       on E1.EmployeeID equals E2.EmployeeID
                       select new EmpVM
                       {
                           EmployeeID = E1.EmployeeID,
                           Forename = E1.Forename,
                           Surname = E1.Surname,
                           Ext = E1.Ext,
                           Email = E1.Email,
                           Active = E1.Active,
                           JobID = E2.JobID
                       });

            if (searchBy == "Forename")
            {
                
                return View(Emp.Where(a => a.Forename.StartsWith(search) && a.Active == true));
            }
            else
            {
               
                return View(Emp.Where(a => a.Surname.StartsWith(search) && a.Active == true));
            }


        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

So what I'm looking for is to link into 3rd table and get Jobs ID to Job name.

Answer (score 0):

with proper relations in the database itself, Linq tools build navigation paths for you and you don't need "join" (it is for joining conditions where a pk-fk relation wouldn't normally exist):

```
var Emp = (from E1 in db.Employee
                   select new EmpVM
                   {
                       E1.EmployeeID,
                       E1.Forename,
                       E1.Surname,
                       E1.Ext,
                       E1.Email,
                       E1.Active,
                       JobID = E1.EmployeeDetails.JobID
// , Job = E1.EmployeeDetails.Job.Name
                   });
```

Looks like employee, employeedetails are 1-to-1, if not, you better start this from EmployeeDetails.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to give your `Employee` an `object` class instance that is of the `Job` type.

```
public class Employee {
 public string EmployeeID {get;set;}
                           public string Forename {get;set;}
                           public string Surname {get;set;}
                           public string Ext {get;set;}
                           public string Email{get;set;}
                           public bool Active {get;set;}
                           public Job Job {get;set;}
}
```

Then you should select them in the following way:

```
var Emp = (from E1 in db.Employee
                       join E2 in db.EmployeeDetails
                       on E1.EmployeeID equals E2.EmployeeID
                       select new EmpVM
                       {
                           EmployeeID = E1.EmployeeID,
                           Forename = E1.Forename,
                           Surname = E1.Surname,
                           Ext = E1.Ext,
                           Email = E1.Email,
                           Active = E1.Active,
                           Job= db.Job.First(x => x.JobID == E2.JobID)
                       });
```

Alternatively, you can try the following with Entity Framework:

```
var Employee = db.Employee.Include(x => x.EmployeeDetails).ThenInclude(y => y.Job);
```

Make sure to add `using System.Data.Entity;` to get the version of Include that takes in a lambda.